# Elastic search - reIndex millions of records based on its date

Tags: elasticsearch

We have millions of records in a date based Index, In  the same index there would be thousands of records belonging to a different date, we want to reIndex all those records to an Index based on its day of the month and year(e.g 2020-08-01, 2020-08-02 etc...), we have to delete the record from source index after reindexing successfully.
I wrote a small script in the query to get all records which do not belong to current date, and started reIndexing using reIndex api, but after processing few hundred api's ES throws "too many requests" error.
I tried to reindex using "wait_for_completion:false" parameter too.
I am not able to group records on date as date_histogram gives only count, cant use bulk api because destination for every record can be different and cant extract destination value for each record.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: How is your current index named and how would you like the new indexes to be called? Are you sure you want an index per day?

Comment: current index is named as "test-YYYY.MM.DD" and would want the new indexes to be named in same manner. "test-" is fixed, we would want the date to be picked from the record so that all the data is indexed appropriately. Yes, we need indexes per day.

Comment: Do you can consider index renaming to (for example test.YYYY.MM.DD-new) in reindex process?

Comment: No, if that was the case i would have used bulk api and got this done.

Comment: So you already have indexes per day but you think that some documents are not located in the correct index according to their timestamp value ?

Comment: Yes, thats right.

Comment: Is it because you've indexed many historical logs and they all landed in the same daily index the day the indexation was carried out?

Comment: no, any day's data can from the source on any day for various reasons. We would run a nightly script which would make sure of moving data to appropriate index. So the option we have is to reIndex api and it doesn't work as expected when records are huge.

Comment: Why don't you modify your ingesters to send the records to the right index in the first place?

Comment: That is not possible, so have to get this option working.

Comment: It's pretty easy to re-route the documents to the right daily index (using reindex API), however, deleting them can only be made using a second call (using delete by query API). Is this something that you could live with?

Comment: We are doing exactly what you mentioned. But the issue arises when there are too many records to re-index and delete the same. That is when we get "too many requests" error.